# git: trying to merge branches, but there are TONS of conflicts, and most of them /shouldn't/ be conflicts

Tags: git, conflict

Here is a lot of what I'm getting:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
code
=======
>>>>>>> Merge branch 'master' of code_url into not_master
```

and there are tons of those occurring multiple times in 40+ files. Is there a different way to merge such that it correctly resolves conflicts on its own? I feel like whenever it encounters any simultaneous difference in a location a file, git decides to flip ALL THE TABLES.

(╯°□°）╯︵ buıbɹǝɯ ʇıb

I looked at rebase, and it MAY have been what I have needed when I started the branch. To start rebasing - I still need to deal with all these conflicts.

Comment: Why need to deal with conflicts? Discard you merge and rebase it.

Comment: doing git rebase master gives tons of the same conflicts.

Comment: If all conflicts are: code in the `HEAD` and nothing in the `Merge` and you want to get all code, do `git merge -s ours` or `git merge -s theirs`. Only one is correct and I always mix up them =(

Answer (score 1):

I've often seen this when git has record of lines being deleted. It doesn't seem to want to auto-merge if a line has been edited in one branch but deleted in another.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether there are line ending differences? The above may stem from a line ending of `\r` in the repo and and `\n` in the working directory.

Comment: that wouldn't help me solve my problem though, cause I'd still have to manually change all the line endings. but anyway, I don't think that's the case... as most of the "conflicts" are added code replacing whitespace (as shown in the example)

Comment: @TheLindyHop - I don't know about "manually"; it would be pretty easy to create a shell script to replace the all line endings in all files for a given folder.